# Node.js socket.setTimeout will sent timeout event to all telnet instances, no matter which one triggered it

Tags: node.js, sockets

I'm trying to experiment the `Net.Server` with a simple socket chat server. What I want to achieve is that, when a client stays idle for a specified time, its connection will be automatically be cut out.

And I've used `socket.setTimeout` to hook some functions like automatically close the socket.

However, while I was using multiple telnets to test my naive server. I found that, no matter which telnet instance has triggered the `timeout` event, it will be sent to every instance.

I had not expected that, and this behavior will close every socket when I hook the auto-close function.

Where have I done wrong?

The code is like below:

```
var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
  socket.setTimeout(MAX_IDLE_TIME); // 60s
  socket.on('timeout', function () {
    socket.write('You seem to be dead, so long!\n'); // should use end
  });
  socket.on('data', function (data) {
    // broadcast logic
  });
}
```

Comment: How are you testing? Are all of the telnet instances not writing to the socket? If so, that's what `socket.setTimeout()` does, it emits `timeout` when the socket has been idle for however long you specify.

Comment: What do you mean by `Are all of the telnet instances not writing to the socket? ` I just opened multiple terminals and used telnet to connect my local server for each one. If you mean there is no input provided, then I did type something in my telnet in different time to differentiate them.

Comment: What I mean is if you open say 3 telnet connections and you don't type anything into the windows for the first two connections but keep typing every so often (some interval < `MAX_IDLE_TIME` milliseconds) into the third window, does the connection in the third window still disconnect (despite the typing to keep the connection from timing out)?

Comment: I tried your way, constantly typing in one telnet. And odd things happened, no telnet will be closed, I guess I've found the problem. You know, my server is a chat server, when a client inputs something, it will be broadcasted to others. And this send activity seems will reset the clocks. I guess I've misunderstood the meaning of inactivity. I'll edit my problem to clariify this.

Comment: @mscdex, As I'm not a native English speaker, I find myself hard to give this question a proper title... Could you help me, in case some newbie like me will take benefits from this in future.